# Prove that any linear combination of the functions $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ (for example:$ f(x)=ae^x + be^{-x}$) can be written as $d \cosh(x-x_o)$

Tags: abstract-algebra

This might be an easy problem for some, but I just can't wrap my head around this.

Prove through algebra, that any linear combination of the functions $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ (for example: $f(x)=ae^x + be^{-x}$) can be written as $f(x)=d\cosh(x-x_0)$
given that a,b>0

Comment: If you look up MathJax you will learn how to make your equations look appropriate.  For example, if you type e^{-x} and enclose that in dollar signs you will get $e^{-x}$.

Comment: As for your question, you will find the answer much more easily if you aren't using the same variable $x$ in both equations.  In general $x$ needs to have a different value in each equation in order to solve this.

Comment: @CMonsour $e^{b+c} = e^b * e^c$. You wrote a typo. ;)

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $e^x=\cosh x+\sinh x$ and $e^{-x}=\cosh x-\sinh x$, so your function can be written
$$
a(\cosh x+\sinh x)+b(\cosh x-\sinh x)=
(a+b)\cosh x+(a-b)\sinh x
$$
and we want to transform it into
$$
k\cosh(x-x_0)=k\cosh x\cosh x_0-k\sinh x\sinh x_0
$$
so we need
$$
\begin{cases}
a+b=k\cosh x_0\\[4px]
a-b=-k\sinh x_0
\end{cases}
$$
Summing and subtracting,
$$
\begin{cases}
k(\cosh x_0-\sinh x_0)=2a \\[4px]
k(\cosh x_0+\sinh x_0)=2b
\end{cases}
$$
Now we can multiply and recall that $\cosh^2x_0-\sinh^2x_0=1$, so we get
$$
k^2=4ab
$$
which gives $k=2\sqrt{ab}$ (because $k$ must be positive).

Finally,
$$
\cosh x_0=\frac{a+b}{2\sqrt{ab}}
$$
Note that a solution exists, because for positive $a$ and $b$,  $a+b\ge2\sqrt{ab}$ (AM-GM inequality). The only thing to check is whether $x_0$ should be positive or negative. But we also have
$$
\sinh x_0=\frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{ab}}
$$
so we'll have $x_0>0$ if $b>a$, $x_0<0$ if $b<a$. If $b=a$ there's not much to do:
$$
ae^x+ae^{-x}=2a\cosh x
$$
so $x_0=0$.

---

Once you have transformed the function into a linear combination of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$, the procedure is not much different from the one with (trigonometric) cosine and sine. Suppose
$$
f(x)=A\cos x+B\sin x
$$
and we want to write it as $f(x)=k\cos(x-\varphi)$. The second expression translates into $k\cos x\cos\varphi+k\sin x\sin\varphi$, so we want
$$
k\cos\varphi=A\qquad k\sin\varphi=B
$$
Here we exploit $\cos^2\varphi+\sin^2\varphi=1$, so
$$
k^2=A^2+B^2
$$
and we can choose $k=\sqrt{A^2+B^2}$ and we also have
$$
\cos\varphi=\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}
\qquad
\sin\varphi=\frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}
$$
which determine $\varphi$.

---

Final note: $\cosh(u-v)=\cosh u\cosh v-\sinh u\sinh v$; indeed, the right hand side can be written as
$$
\frac{e^{u}+e^{-u}}{2}
\frac{e^{v}+e^{-v}}{2}
-
\frac{e^{u}-e^{-u}}{2}
\frac{e^{v}-e^{-v}}{2}
$$
Do the multiplications and simplify recalling $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think your answer is way too complicated and smart, than what my teacher actually expects me to answer.
He just wants me to show how a function: f(x)=a*$e^{x}$ + b*$e^{-x}$ can be written as f(x)= d*cosh(x-$x_{0}$)

Is there a way you can do it without differentiating?
Also I forgot to write that a,b>0.
I'm sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Carl Does the second method require differentiation?

Comment: Give me 1 minute.

Comment: @Carl I removed the part with differentiation

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I think I have to sit down and scrutinize this, before I really understand it.
I'm very grateful for the help.

Comment: @Carl It's not much different from writing $a\cos x+b\sin x=k\cos(x-\varphi)$.

Comment: Would you mind showing that to me as well?
Maybe it will enhance my understanding of the entire thing. Of course you don't have to.

Comment: @Carl Added, with some other details

Comment: I'm am very grateful sir.

Comment: Could you clarify why this is true?
k*cosh(x−$x_{0}$)=k*cosh(x)*cosh($x_{0}$)−k*sinh(x)*sinh($x_{0}$)

Comment: @Carl Just expand the right hand side with the definitions of $\cosh$ and $\sinh$, recalling that $e^{u+v}=e^{u}e^v$.

Comment: Why must k be a positive number?

Comment: @Carl Because $ae^x+be^{-x}>0$ and $\cosh(x-x_0)>0$

Answer (score 0):

Making

$$
a = e^{\lambda_1}\sigma(a)\\
b = e^{\lambda_2}\sigma(b)
$$

with $\sigma(\cdot)$ the sign function, and making $\lambda = \frac{\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{2}, \lambda_0 = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}$ we have

$$
a e^x+b e^{-x} = 2e^{\lambda_0}\left(\frac{\sigma(a)e^{x+\lambda}+\sigma(b)e^{-(x+\lambda)}}{2}\right)
$$